# How can I determine differences between two circular distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, matlab, circular-statistics

I have circular datasets. I am using this MATLAB package to perform tests on my data. https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10676-circular-statistics-toolbox-directional-statistics .
I have two distributions which show a significant difference when I apply Kuiper two sample test (which is analogous to the K-S test), but fails the Watson-Williams multi-sample test (which
Can be used as a one-way ANOVA test for circular data).
I understand, the later is a test for checking if the mean of the two distributions are equal, which my dataset fails. But, it is significantly different when I use Kuiper test, which means the distributions can have different mean, location, or dispersion. However, I don't know how should I know explicitly what is the reason that they are significantly different when I apply a different test.

Comment: They're testing different alternatives. The more specific test should have better power against that specific alternative but little or no power against the other alternatives the more general test checks for. You need to decide what it is you want to test for and then use the best available test for that.